# ModuleNotFoundError on Azure app function although requirements.txt exists

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, requirements.txt

I published a python 3.10 function app to azure, locally the function runs successfully.

The deployment is successful, but executing the function on cloud, returning the following error:

`Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. For more info, please refer the troubleshooting guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 387, in _handle__function_load_request func = loader.load_function( File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 48, in call raise extend_exception_message(e, message) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 44, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/azure-functions-...`

The requirements.txt file exists in the root folder and contains list of all packages including cv

`opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5.62`

`opencv-python==4.5.5.62`

(I can see it in Azure portal -> Function App -> App Files)

What am I missing?

Comment: Please share your function code

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin python code is huge, it uses cv, It seems like requirements.txt not running at all in the cloud or not uploading packages etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that these two configurations were in the function app.

Removing them enabled the installation of packages specified in the requirements.txt file:

```
{
        "name": "ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD",
        "value": "false",
        "slotSetting": false
},
{
        "name": "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT",
        "value": "false",
        "slotSetting": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a python 3.10 HTTP triggered function having below code.

**Function code**-

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import cv2


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    logging.info(f'OpenCV version: {cv2.__version__}')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

**requirements.txt**-

```
azure-functions
opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5.62
```

I have debugged my function in vs code and able to get the expected output while executing the function locally.

[image]

Post publishing the function to function app, I am also getting successful output.

[image]

If requirement.txt file is containing all the modules post deployment then your function should work alike me. If the issue still persists, you can consider deploying the function to a freshly created function app.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I created a new function using your code, and then I was able to compare and figure out the issue I had (which is posted in the next answer).